# Image issue in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

This is my project folder structure.
I have resources folder under webapp.
  Source
    _ main
      -webapp
        - resources 
            adminlogin.jpeg

I have one jsp page adminlogin.jsp which contain 1 image.But When ever I try to access this page I get page but not image.
This is my SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <i><context:component-scan base-package="ShoppingOnline" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   <context:annotation-config />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
   </i>
```

This is my jsp page

```
 <html> 
 <body>
 <img src="/adminlogin.jpeg" alt="ADMIN LOGIN">
 </body>
 </html>
```

I have seen many example in your site very one has given one soultion.
     
but no has explain how its work in folder structure with example.I have made project in eclipse with the help of maven and In my folder structure the resources file is inside the web-inf folder.I haven't seen a single good example in this sites.
Please if u explain,explain with a good example how it is work if the resource is inside the web inf folder and when the resources is outside the web inf folder.
Please also let me know my mistake.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your static files to webapps > resources

servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

then static files can be accessible from the page.

in Jsp:

```
<img src="/resources/images/yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: Have you seen my project structure.There is 1 image inside
Source _ 
........main
 -........webapp

 -........ resources
 ...........adminlogin.jpeg
I have done that I have added my static folder in 
<mvc:resources mapping>
I have added in the code.

Comment: Just change **<img src="/resources/adminlogin.jpeg" alt="ADMIN LOGIN">**

Comment: Hey Thanks It is work for me.
I have one more issue .Please some body tell me if my resources folder is inside web-inf and how to access it.

Comment: <img src="/resources/adminlogin.jpeg" alt="ADMIN LOGIN">
Yes This the same thing I have done nothing else and its work.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow.I have no rights to give you 1 point sorry.